# Free probability and projections

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, trace, von-neumann-algebras, projection

Let $(\mathcal{A},\varphi)$ be a free probability space, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a von Neumann algebra and $\varphi$ a finite and faithful trace. Let furthermore $p\in\mathcal{A}$ be a projection. Consider a $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and assume that $p$ and $A$ are free. This implies 
$$\varphi(p A p)=\varphi(p)\varphi(A)\varphi(p).$$ But this is equal to $$\varphi(p)\varphi(Ap)$$ and since $p$ is a projection and $\varphi$ tracial, we have 
$$\varphi(p)\varphi(pAp).$$ We therefore have 
$$\varphi(pAp)=\varphi(p)\varphi(pAp),$$ which implies that $$p=1.$$
I am pretty sure I am missing something since I don't think this is true...

Please help :)

Comment: Why would $\phi(p)^2\phi(A)$ be equal to $\phi(p)\phi(Ap)$?

Comment: Since $A$ and $p$ are free with respect to $\varphi$ we have that $$\varphi(A p)=\varphi(A)\varphi(p).$$

Comment: Sorry, just figured out what the problem is. It just not true that $$\varphi(p A p)=\varphi(p)\varphi(A)\varphi(p).$$ We have that $$\varphi(p A p) = \varphi(p A)=\varphi(p)\varphi(A)$$ but that's it and there is no problem... Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freness is not multiplicativity. It works for a product of two elements, because $\varphi(x-\varphi(x) I)=0$ and $\varphi(y-\varphi(y)I)=0$, so
$$
0=\varphi((x-\varphi(x)I)(y-\varphi(y)I)=\varphi(xy)-\varphi(x)\varphi(y). 
$$
But if you have three or more elements, the above does not give you multiplicativity. The way to express $\varphi(xyz)$ in terms of values of products of less degree requires *free cumulants*.